# swift usesPreciseCollisionDetection does not work?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, detection, skphysicsbody

i have made an app where you need to shoot on an enemy but sometimes the bullet goes through the enemy. [swift sprite kit game when I shoot on a enemy sometimes the bullet goes trough the enemy, how can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073605/swift-sprite-kit-game-when-i-shoot-on-a-enemy-sometimes-the-bullet-goes-trough-t)

so i added usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true.
but the bullet sometimes still goes trough the enemy. so my question was did i do something wrong or is usesPreciseCollisionDetection not working?

thank you for reading my question I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Are the 2 objects supposed to collide, contact or both?

Comment: I made it so if the bullet hits the enemy the enemy explodes and the bullet is removed

Answer (score 2):

You are using `moveTo` to move your bullets,  Physics Engine does not work with `moveTo` the way you want it to,  `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` will not do anything

As far as your Physics World is concerned, your bullet is stationary.  You are just playing God and performing some kind of molecular transportation to move items.

You need to use functions like `applyImpulse` or even just give the physicsBody a velocity if you want this to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem that is collision was sometimes not detected even when usesPreciseCollisionDetection was set to true and both SKPhysicsBody were rectangles. In my case usesPreciseCollisionDetection for some reason started working much better when I changed one of the SKPhysicsBody to circle instead of rectangle. Try changing your bullet physics body to circle, it seems that collision detection algorithm with circles is more precise so that might help you.